# Best HashMap initial capacity while indexing a List

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, hashmap

I have a list (`List<T> list`) and I want to index its objects by their ids using a map (`HashMap<Integer, T> map`). I always use `list.size()` as the **initial capacity** in the `HashMap` constructor,like in the code below. Is this the best initial capacity to be used in this case?

**Note**: I'll never add more items to the map.

```
List<T> list = myList;
Map<Integer, T> map = new HashMap<Integer, T>(list.size());
for(T item : list) {
    map.put(item.getId(), item);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend: 1) Declare your variable as `Map` instead of `HashMap`, 2) Let this kind of problems to the JVM, if you notice **with a profiler** that is giving your performance hits, then start evaluating it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza generally yes, agreed, but this is such a common use-case that we might as-well get rid of re-sizes

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you wish to avoid rehashing the `HashMap`, and you know that no other elements will be placed into the `HashMap`, then you must take into account the load factor as well as the initial capacity.  The load factor [for a `HashMap` defaults to 0.75](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

The calculation to determine whether rehashing is necessary occurs whenever an new entry is added, e.g. `put` places a new key/value.  So if you specify an initial capacity of `list.size()`, and a load factor of 1, then it will rehash after the last `put`.  So to prevent rehashing, use a load factor of 1 and a capacity of `list.size() + 1`.

**EDIT**

Looking at the `HashMap` source code, it will rehash if the *old* size meets or exceeds the threshold, so it won't rehash on the last `put`.  So it looks like a capacity of `list.size()` should be fine.

```
HashMap<Integer, T> map = new HashMap<Integer, T>(list.size(), 1.0);
```

Here's the relevant piece of `HashMap` source code:

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold)
        resize(2 * table.length);
}
```

Comment: @Eric just look at the source and search for "resize(" . http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.resize%28%29 It's probably done the same way. Line 676

Comment: is it just me or doesn't anybody know that *a load of 1.0 is a really bad idea*?!

Comment: @arnaud Normally, yes, that would be a bad idea. But the OP did state "**Note**: I'll never add more items to the map."

Comment: @rgettman: if you know how hash map work internally, you would notice that you not only screw up your inserts but also your reads. All operation would become O(N) instead of O(1) because you'll have to jump from bucket to bucket because of collisions everywhere

Comment: You know that you set as the correct ansower the WRONG ANSWER ?

Comment: And note that the initial capacity will internally be rounded up to the next power of two. So a capacity of 200 will be rounded up to 256.
If HashMap wouldn't round up to a power-of-two value for `capacity`, some buckets would be never used. The bucket index for where to put the map data is determined by `bucketIndex = hashCode(key) & (capacity-1)`.
This is true for both Java 7 and 8, afaik.

Comment: Using load factor of 1 is a bad idea considering the fact that hash collisions will increase if there are less free buckets. Its a tradeoff between space and time that java designers use load factor of 0.75 as default. If you are not sure about load factor internals, do not touch this default. Now, If you go with load factor of 0.75 instead of 1, the capacity of map that shouldn't cause it to rehash can be calculated with initialCapacity = (Expected no. of elements/0.75)+1. Period.

Comment: @ShaileshPratapwar I assume you take the ceil function of that formula too. e.g. `initCapacity = ceil(nExpectedElements / loadFactor) + 1`

Answer (score 23):

The 'capacity' keyword is incorrect by definition and isn't used in the way typically expected.

By default the 'load factor' of a HashMap is 0.75, this means that when the  number of entries in a HashMap reaches 75% of the capacity supplied, it will resize the array and rehash.

For example if I do:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(100);
```

When I am adding the 75th entry, the map will resize the Entry table to 2 * map.size() (or 2 * table.length). So we can do a few things:

1. Change the load factor - this could impact the performance of the map
2. Set the initial capacity to list.size() / 0.75 + 1

The best option is the latter of the two, let me explain what's going on here:

```
list.size() / 0.75
```

This will return list.size() + 25% of list.size(), for example if my list had a size of 100 it would return 133. We then add 1 to it as the map is resized if the size of it is equal to 75% of the initial capacity, so if we had a list with a size of 100 we would be setting the initial capacity to 134, this would mean that adding all 100 entries from the list would not incur any resize of the map.

End result:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(list.size() / 0.75 + 1);
```

Comment: Looking at the JDK source code, the actual table size is rounded up to the nearest power of 2. Also, re. your statement "By default the 'load factor' of a HashMap is 0.75, this means that when the number of entries in a HashMap reaches 75% of the capacity supplied, it will resize the array and rehash." - to be a bit pedantic, the resize only happens when the entries exceed (not reach) 75% of the capacity. So, for example, with a specified initial capacity of 64 and load factor of 0.5, you can put 32 entries in without resizing.

Comment: Also 100 / 0.75 = 133, not that it changes anything

Answer (score 16):

Guava's [`Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMapWithExpectedSize%28int%29) uses this helper method to calculate initial capacity for the default load factor of `0.75`, based on some expected number of values:

```
/**
 * Returns a capacity that is sufficient to keep the map from being resized as
 * long as it grows no larger than expectedSize and the load factor is >= its
 * default (0.75).
 */
static int capacity(int expectedSize) {
    if (expectedSize < 3) {
        checkArgument(expectedSize >= 0);
        return expectedSize + 1;
    }
    if (expectedSize < Ints.MAX_POWER_OF_TWO) {
        return expectedSize + expectedSize / 3;
    }
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE; // any large value
}
```

reference: [source](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#line.201)

From the `newHashMapWithExpectedSize` documentation:

> Creates a `HashMap` instance, with a high enough "initial capacity" that
>   it *should* hold `expectedSize` elements without growth. This behavior
>   cannot be broadly guaranteed, but it is observed to be true for
>   OpenJDK 1.6. It also can't be guaranteed that the method isn't
>   inadvertently *oversizing* the returned map.

Comment: +1. This is the simplest and the easiest solution for those who don't want to understand the internals of the map, and just want something that works as expected.

Answer (score 14):

What you're doing is fine. In this way you're sure that the hash map has *at least* enough capacity for the initial values. If you have more information regarding the usage patterns of the hash map (example: is it updated frequently? are many new elements added frequently?), you might want to set a bigger initial capacity (for instance, `list.size() * 2`), but never lower. Use a profiler to determine if the initial capacity is falling short too soon.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @PaulBellora for suggesting that the initial capacity should be set to `(int)Math.ceil(list.size() / loadFactor)` (typically, the default load factor is 0.75) in order to avoid an initial resize.

Comment: "the hash map has at least enough capacity for the initial values" - I don't think this is true with the default load factor of 0.75.

Comment: @PaulBellora the initial capacity is the same size as the one specified in the `initialCapacity` parameter. The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity (initial or not) is automatically increased

Comment: Right, so with a load factor of `0.75` and an initial capacity of `n`, putting `n` values would cause it to resize.

Comment: @PaulBellora so you're suggesting that the initial capacity should be size()/.75 to avoid an initial resize? makes sense, I'll update my answer

Comment: Exactly +1 - you can see Guava is doing the same thing in the snippet [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15844138/697449) references.

Comment: So, if I change my load factor to 1.0, like @rgettman suggested. Then `new HashMap(list.size(), 1.0)` will have the same behaviour of `new HashMap(Math.ceiling(list.size() / 0.75)` in my case, where I'll never add more itens to the hash map?

Comment: It'd be the same, but it's a bad practice to wait until the last moment to increase the hash map's size, that's why the load factor is usually less than 1

Comment: Ok. But I'm asking only in my specific case, where I'll never add another item to the hash map. In this specific case i would be a bad practice?

Comment: @italo in that case both rgettman's answer and my own would be equivalent. Also, if you want to enforce the invariant that the hashmap never changes, maybe you should make it immutable using `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`

Answer (score 4):

According to the [reference documentation of java.util.HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> The expected number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into account when setting its initial capacity, so as to minimize the number of rehash operations. If the initial capacity is greater than the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash operations will ever occur.

This means, if you know in advance, how many entries the HashMap should store, you can prevent rehashing by choosing an appropriate initial capacity **and load factor**. However:

> As a general rule, the default load factor (.75) offers a good tradeoff between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the operations of the HashMap class, including get and put).

Answer (score 2):

#### Java 19

Though this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15844186/3764965) is still valid, it's worth noting that as of Java 19, there are in-built static methods to construct hash structures with appropriate initial capacities.

```java
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = HashMap.newHashMap(10);
```

The implementation uses `DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f`.

There are also the very same methods for other hash structures using the very same implementation from `HashMap` on top of the `DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR`. Here is a complete list:

- `HashMap.newHashMap(10)`
- `HashSet.newHashSet(10)`
- `LinkedHashMap.newLinkedHashMap(10)`
- `LinkedHashSet.newLinkedHashSet(10)`
- `WeakHashMap.newWeakHashMap(10)`

Interestingly, there is no such method for `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 1):

**The rule of thumb if you don't know load factor/capacity internals :**

```
initialCapacityToUse = (Expected No. of elements in map / 0.75) + 1
```

With this initial capacity value, the rehash will not occur for storing given expected no. of elements in map.

Comment: Could you explain why do we need +1?

Comment: I guess that's not actual, but still, we need +1 this is to cover the rest of the division. For example, we reserve space for 5 elements. A map will be resized once it reaches 0.75 loads. So 5 should be less than 75% of the map reserved space. 5*(4/3) = 6.66. We need that to be rounded to 7, but it will be rounded down to 6. So 5 out of 7 is 71%, and 5 out of 6 is 83%. In the case with 6 reserved places once you add the last map will be resized. Still, I guess the proper way is to change load factor to 1 and reserve exactly 5 elements.