# prevent hashmap to resized to its double of current size

Tags: java, hashmap

We have a HashMap with the size of one million. We have to store one million and 100 objects but we don’t want the HashMap to be increased to the size (2 millions) which doubles its current size (1 million) for just 100 objects.

EDIT:
I want to optimize the resizing of hashmap. Since for storing only 100 objects we need to allocate size of 1 million objects. so that's waste of memory

How we can overcome this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best HashMap initial capacity while indexing a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844035/best-hashmap-initial-capacity-while-indexing-a-list)

Comment: @Danielson actually, this question have nothing to do with that one.

Comment: It has to do with initial size and when it updates its allocation. I should've linked to the accepted answer instead of the question

Comment: I'm guessing that you are asking how to have a size limit on your hashmap? is that right?

Comment: @nafas: I want to optimize the resizing of hashmap. Since for string only 100 objects we need to allocate size of 1 million objects. so that's waste of memory

Comment: @Danielson: Can you please highlight which part of answer will solve my problem( since you think that its  a duplicate)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15844186/928952

Comment: I would make a new class, extending from `HashMap` and override the relevant methods. Then you can change the resizing policy as you like (for example, never add more than `100 000MB` on resize or something).

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` capacity is implemented to be a power of two, so if 2^20 (1048576) is not enough for you, you'll have to go with 2^21 (2097152).

EDIT:

Actually, you could control the capacity be specifying a high load factor.

If the exact max number of entries is 1000100, the capacity of the HashMap will be doubled if the number of entries reaches capacity * load factor. So if the capacity is 1048576 and you don't want it to expand to 2097152, you need a load factor around 0.954 or higher.

So initializing the instance with the following constructor should do the trick :

```
 HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<> (1048576, 0.954);
```

Relevant code (JDK 6) :

```
public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
    ...
    // Find a power of 2 >= initialCapacity
    int capacity = 1;
    while (capacity < initialCapacity)
        capacity <<= 1;

    this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
    threshold = (int)(capacity * loadFactor);
    table = new Entry[capacity];
    ...
}
```

and

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold) // this is what you want to avoid
        resize(2 * table.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the key and have

```
Map<Key1, Map<Key2, Value>
```

Use for one Map a TreeMap implementation.
If the second Maps are TreeMaps they are filled optimally, and if the major Map is a HashMap, maybe with a high loadFactor (second constructor parameter), then that should be fine. Also collisions then are better dealt with.

You could create your own Map implementation wrapping that.